# Android Studio HAXM Installer Error

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, haxm

Im New to Android Studio Guys and following a tutorial in YouTube for developing Android Apps. I Have Installed the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) but when launching the AVD It Says the HAXM is not installed... For the matter im using a AMD Processor..

[Installed HAXM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga9UT.png)

[AVD Showing Not installed HAXM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mYYb.png)

Comment: Have you tried restarting Android Studio or your PC after the installation?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried manually install **intelhaxm-android.exe**? It's in your sdk folder **extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager**.

Comment: Yea when i tried it showed this: 

http://imgur.com/DrHjyXK

It Maybe Because Im Using a AMD Procesor and not an Intel One?

Answer (score 0):

The VT-x technology as well as the HAXM are unique to Intel processors. In the case of AMD processors, AMD-V is the counterpart in the virtualization tech front. Installation of HAXM in an AMD processor will not have any impact and hence the error "your cpu doesn't support vt-x or svm".

Reference link: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/emulator

As stated in the link above

> For best performance with Android Emulator 2.0, your system should
>   meet the following specifications: Windows: Intel® processor with
>   support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable
>   (XD) Bit functionality. AMD and Intel Atom processors do not support
>   VT-x virtual machine acceleration. Linux: Intel® processor with
>   support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable
>   (XD) Bit functionality or AMD processors with support for AMD
>   Virtualization™ (AMD-V™) 64-bit Operating Systems.

I would suggest to use an ARM image for the emulator instead of an Intel image. This would not require the use of HAXM nor VT-x.

Answer (score 0):

with AMD and V enabled you only need to do one more thing..

that is you have to install the KVM extension for your particular kernel.

see this [blog for details](http://craigthomas.ca/blog/2014/06/06/android-emulator-vm-acceleration-on-amd/)

Comment: The Blog you Said Is Given For Linux.... So in Windows-person Words, I Need to install KVM and the Intel Atom Image In My PC?